# Cersei's Motives for Tommen

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones season 6 episode 10, what was Cersei's motives for

> burning Tommen's body and burying him at the place the Great Sept stood instead of entombing him beside his relatives? This is what Cersei says:
> *"He should be with his grandfather. His Brother. His Sister. Burn him. Bury his ashes where the Sept once stood."*

I read this as Cersei considering two options, but the reason for the decision is not clear to me. It could be:

- > Cersei felt Tommen was not worth to be entombed at Casterly Rock because it was a suicide.
- > Cersei wanted people to think Tommen was killed in the explosion. However, if people think Cersei was behind it, then they will think she knowingly killed him on purpose?
- > Cersei wanted to show tribute by burying him at the Great Sept
- > Other?

Answer (score 15):

**None of the above.**

> **[Tommen](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Tommen_Baratheon)** is cremated and his ashes spread over the ruins of the **[Great Sept of Baelor](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Sept_of_Baelor)** where **[Tywin](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Tywin_Lannister)**, **[Joffrey](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Joffrey_Baratheon)** and **[Myrcella](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Myrcella_Baratheon)** were also buried.

See this quote from his wiki page:

> Later, Cersei visits Tommen's body and orders him to be burned and buried in what is left of the Great Sept of Baelor, saying he should be buried where his grandfather, brother, and sister are buried.
> <sup>*-http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Tommen_Baratheon#Season_6*</sup>

Comment: Why not quite the actual episode, instead of a wiki?

Comment: From a production/storytelling point of view, there's also a bit of a parallel between this scene and Ramsay's coldness earlier regarding Miranda's burial. I see it as a nod to the viewers: Cersei's "one redeeming feature" is gone, she's lost the only thing to live for beyond megalomania and revenge, and now we see her being portrayed in a way that casts parallels with Ramsay: expect her story to get even darker!

Comment: @OrangeDog There's nothing the script which adds any more than what the OP has already included.

Comment: I edited the question to include the line. I interpreted what Cersei says is that will not be buried in the same place as everyone else. But I do see how it could be read that he is to be. Is there anything in the show or book that says where the others are buried?

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer section for spoiler block reasons.

You say:

> Cersei wanted people to think Tommen was killed in the explosion. However, if people think Cersei was behind it, then they will think she knowingly killed him on purpose?

Quite the opposite!

> Making people think Tommen died in the explosion is more likely to make people think she *didn't* cause it it.